# Top off differential fluid

Tags: b-body

How do you top off / fill the differential on a 1996 Chevy Caprice?  Can it be done without taking the cover off and changing the gasket?  Any gotchas to watch out for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods I use.One is to attach a piece of hose to the pointed tip of the gear oil container and stick the other end in the differential.Then squeeze the bottle.The other method is to use a suction gun that looks like a big metal hypodermic syringe.You suck the oil in then push in the plunger and squirt the oil into the fill hole.